# I don't understand why my function returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that checks if a given string is a palindrome. I had some difficulty getting it to work with capital letters, but I think(?) that's fixed now. The issue is that when I pass my string into the checkString() function, it returns undefined and I don't know why.

```js
const palindromes = function(string) {
  const originalString = string;
  const reverseString = string.split("").reverse().join("");
  const check = reverseString.slice(-1);

  if (check === check.toUpperCase()) {
    const newString = reverseString.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + originalString.slice(1);
    checkString(originalString, newString);
  } else {
    checkString(originalString, reverseString);
  };
};


const checkString = function(originalString, newString) {
  if (originalString === newString) {
    return true;
  };
  return false;
};

console.log(palindromes("Racecar"));
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: you don't return anything in `palindromes` ... do you? nope, just checked, there is no `return` in palindromes

Comment: Just put a return before `checkString` in palindromes function.

Comment: code hint, in `checkString`, you can just `return originalString === newString`

Comment: @Bravo in fact, the function that just does `===` isn't needed. You can compare directly.

Comment: @VLAZ indeed you can

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the value returned by `checkString()` function.

```js
const palindromes = function(string) {
  const originalString = string;
  const reverseString = string.split("").reverse().join("");
  const check = reverseString.slice(-1);

  if (check === check.toUpperCase()) {
    const newString = reverseString.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + originalString.slice(1);
    return checkString(originalString, newString);
  } else {
    return checkString(originalString, reverseString);
  };
};


const checkString = function(originalString, newString) {
  if (originalString === newString) {
    return true;
  };
  return false;
};

console.log(palindromes("Racecar"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code even better:

```js
const palindromes = function(string) {
  const originalString = string.toUpperCase(); // make string to uppercase
  const reverseString = originalString.split("").reverse().join(""); // reverse string
  return originalString === reverseString; // inline compare and RETURN the value!
};


console.log(palindromes("Racecar"));
console.log(palindromes("stackoverflow"));
```